# wxpython - how to remove gray rectangle made from statictext

Tags: wxpython

I'm beginner in 'wxPython'.
I'm trying to make my GUI program with python.
But I can't set background transparency to 'StaticText'.
I tried 'SetBackground(), SetTransparent()'
But gray rectangle remained.
I want to know how to remove gray rectangle behind the 'hamster'.
Thanks...

[image]

Comment: As far as I know the only way is to use a [drawing context](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.DC-class.html#DrawText) and use that to write the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to subclass `wx.StaticText` to get it to work. This fellow figured it out:

- http://www.keacher.com/994/transparent-static-text-in-wxpython/

It would appear that you need to override its `on_paint` method.

For the ultimate in flexibility though, I would recommend using `wx.DC` or `wx.GCDC`. See the wxPython demo for some examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It works. I used dc.DrawText instead of wx.StaticText.